# Oracle SQL - How do I sequentially iterate through this result set to remove certain records?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

My current output is shown in the image below. I highlighted the records I want removed.

[image: Current Output]

I am primarily a C# developer, so my "pseudo-logic" to get the results I want is as follows:

```
List<int> resultSet = new List<int>();

for(int i = 1; i < table.Length; i++)
{
    if((c_id[i] == c_id[i-1])&&
       (sub_id[i] < sub_id[i-1]))
    {
        resultSet.Remove(contact_event_id[i]);
        resultSet.Remove(contact_event_id[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Essentially, what I want done is to remove records from the result set that are "paired" by c_id. Two records are considered a **pair** if:

- Record i and record i-1 have **the same c_id**
- Record i has a **sub_id that's less than** record i-1

A few important notes:

1. I only have *read access* to this database/table.
2. The ce_id is the primary key of this table, which we'll call **e_table**
3. Do not rely on the e_date for ordering...use ce_id.

The SQL I have so far is below. Notice the "..." in the *having* clause; this is to keep things as simple as possible for the implementation. There is a lot more logic involved with this task that isn't worth getting into unless it's really needed.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM e_table
    WHERE e_date >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1))
    AND e_date <= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) || ' 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    AND sub_id IN(2, 1)
) ce
WHERE ce.c_id IN
(
    select c_id
    from e_table
    where e_date >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1))
    AND e_date <= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) || ' 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    group by c_id
    having ...
)
ORDER BY ce_id ASC;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any elaboration is needed.

**Edit #1 as pointed out by MT0 in the comments:**
Consider the following record set:
[image]

Notice how, with my current proposed logic, the two middle records are considered pairs. They should be removed; no question about it. However, see afterwards how, when removed, the remaining two rows also meet the requirements of being pairs at first glance? They **should not be** considered as such as they are not adjacent in the original output. In this case, I suppose the e_date will have to be utilized after all. However, it is important to note that the times of these pairs, while seemingly identical, can differ by up to one second. No matter what, the ordering still needs to be done with the ce_id, as ordering by the date can cause the sub_id to switch places inappropriately.

**Edit #2:**

The above image is just to show that the implementation should occur in one pass through the recordset produced from my query. **It is not actually possible to have two consecutive 1's in a row for the sub_id, as explained in the comments throughout.**

**Edit #3**

DML as requested by MT0:

```
CREATE TABLE e_table (
  ce_id  INT,
  c_id   CHAR(3),
  sub_id INT
);

INSERT INTO e_table
SELECT 1, '421', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '421', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '359', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '220', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '288', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '402', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, '348', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, '402', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, '402', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '062', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, '062', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '062', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, '029', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '325', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, '549', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, '278', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, '852', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, '490', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19, '490', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, '490', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, '490', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, '490', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 23, '781', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 24, '019', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25, '019', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 26, '082', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 27, '082', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28, '082', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 29, '990', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, '019', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 31, '041', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What does "record i-1" mean?  I can think of easier ways to identify those records.

Comment: can you upload the data scripts for your record set

Comment: @Gordan "Record i-1" means "the previous record." If we think of it as an iteration through each record one by one, with i being the current record, i-1 simply means the one before.

Comment: using lead or lag to group the record pairs together may be a better approach

Comment: If you have four rows all adjacent with the same `C_ID` and with the `SUB_ID`s: `2`,`2`,`1`,`1` (in their respective order) then how many should be deleted? Just the 2nd and 3rd rows because the outer pair have `SUB_ID` equal to their adjacent row or all four rows as, once the middle two rows are deleted then the outer two will also fit the criteria?

Comment: There will never exist a case with two subsequent 1's for a SUB_ID. A "1" will ALWAYS have a "2" beforehand.

Comment: can you show the query that is producing the current result?

Comment: The SQL at the bottom of my post is what's producing the current record set.

Comment: If you have four rows with the `C_ID`s: `1`, `2`, `2`, `1` and the `SUB_ID`s: `2`, `2`, `1`, `1` (in their respective order) then how many rows should be deleted?

Comment: @MT0 I see what you're getting at now. Here is how the scenario will play out. Start at the second row. Look at the c_id of the previous row. We see it's not equal. So iterate to the third row. Look at the c_id of the previous row. We see they're equal. So now check if the sub_id of the current row is less than that of the previous row. It is indeed less. So remove the current and previous rows (#2 and #3). Move to "row #4." Check the previous row's c_id. They're equal, so check the sub_id's. The current sub_id is less than the previous sub_id... However, this should not be removed.

Comment: Therefore, we should only consider records legitimate pairs if they are **exactly** next to each other **in the original query.** Great catch @MT0, I'll edit my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the row numbers for each c_id ordered by ce_id.

Then join on the previous row and check to see if the sub_id value is > or <.

Because of a self-join use `union all` to get ce_id's from both the tables and exclude those rows from the output.

```
with x as (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by c_id order by ce_id) rn from t
)
select * from t 
where ce_id not in (    
select x1.ce_id
from x x1
join x x2 on x1.c_id = x2.c_id and x1.rn = x2.rn-1
where x1.sub_id > x2.sub_id
union all
select x2.ce_id
from x x1
join x x2 on x1.c_id = x2.c_id and x1.rn = x2.rn-1
where x1.sub_id > x2.sub_id
)
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/FZJC13426)**

Edit: To include the current query of the OP as a cte and using this answer to get the result,

```
with t as (/*your query here*/)
, x as (
select t.*,row_number() over(partition by c_id order by ce_id) rn from t
)
select * from t 
where ce_id not in (    
select x1.ce_id
from x x1
join x x2 on x1.c_id = x2.c_id and x1.rn = x2.rn-1
where x1.sub_id > x2.sub_id
union all
select x2.ce_id
from x x1
join x x2 on x1.c_id = x2.c_id and x1.rn = x2.rn-1
where x1.sub_id > x2.sub_id
)
```

Comment: Hi vkp, where would I include my current query in this solution?

Comment: can you not replace the current query with this solution? i assumed what you showed was a table by itself. If it is not so, have your entire query as a `cte` and include this query thereafter.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use a cte here since you already use one in your solution. Can you help me construct it? I see in your sample demo the output is correct, I would just like to get it to work with my current query. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks so much @vkp! Works like a charm.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius http://rextester.com/HBH62586 - Rows 18 - 21 are deleted but you stated in the comments (and latest edit) that only rows 19 & 20 should be deleted in this situation.

Comment: @MT0 Right, but remember, there will never be two consecutive sub_ids with a value of 1. The way you set up the table in rextester has two consecutive 1's, when in reality, this isn't possible within the real data.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius You stated in your edit that there can never be two consecutive `sub_id`s with the same `c_id` with a value of `1` but there **can** be two consecutive `sub_id`s with different `c_id`s with a value of `1`. The link I posted has this latter case (specifically the case highlighted in the edit to the OP) and too many rows are deleted.

Comment: There will never exist a case with two subsequent 1's for a SUB_ID, regardless of the ce_id value. My edit in the original post was to demonstrate that this implementation should only occur in one pass. I realize the image is misleading since it shows two consecutive 1's, but this is not a possible case.

Comment: @MT0 Sorry for the confusion here; I hope my latest edit on the original post clears things up.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius http://rextester.com/TOITWY5163 No consecutive 1s but rows 18,19,20 & 22 are deleted - it should only delete 19 & 20 from that set of rows.

Comment: rows 18,20 have the same `ce_id` `001` and have 2 followed by 1 for `c_id`. so they are excluded.

Comment: @vkp Rows 19 & 20 should be excluded but Rows 18 & 22 should not; however they all are excluded.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE e_table (
  ce_id  INT,
  c_id   CHAR(3),
  sub_id INT
);

INSERT INTO e_table
SELECT  1, '421', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, '421', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, '359', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, '220', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, '288', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, '402', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, '348', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, '402', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, '402', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, '152', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, '062', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, '062', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, '062', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, '029', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, '062', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, '325', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, '549', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, '001', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 19, '002', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, '002', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 21, '001', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22, '001', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT e.*,
         CASE WHEN (   LEAD( c_id   ) OVER ( ORDER BY ce_id ) = c_id
                   AND LEAD( sub_id ) OVER ( ORDER BY ce_id ) < sub_id )
                OR (   LAG( c_id    ) OVER ( ORDER BY ce_id ) = c_id
                   AND LAG( sub_id  ) OVER ( ORDER BY ce_id ) > sub_id )
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END AS to_delete
  FROM   e_table e
)
WHERE to_delete = 0;
```

**Output**:

*(Rows 8, 9, 11, 12, 19 & 20 are removed.)*

```
     CE_ID C_ID     SUB_ID  TO_DELETE
---------- ---- ---------- ----------
         1 421           2          0 
         2 421           2          0 
         3 359           2          0 
         4 220           2          0 
         5 288           2          0 
         6 402           2          0 
         7 348           2          0 
        10 152           2          0 
        13 062           2          0 
        14 029           2          0 
        15 062           1          0 
        16 325           2          0 
        17 549           2          0 
        18 001           2          0 
        21 001           1          0 
        22 001           2          0
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT e.*,
         CASE WHEN (   LEAD( c_id   ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY ce_id ) = c_id
                   AND LEAD( sub_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY ce_id ) < sub_id )
                OR (   LAG( c_id    ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY ce_id ) = c_id
                   AND LAG( sub_id  ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c_id ORDER BY ce_id ) > sub_id )
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
              END AS to_delete
  FROM   e_table e
)
WHERE to_delete = 0
ORDER BY ce_id;
```

**Output**:

*(Rows 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 18, 19, 20 and 21 are removed.)*

```
     CE_ID C_ID     SUB_ID  TO_DELETE
---------- ---- ---------- ----------
         1 421           2          0 
         2 421           2          0 
         3 359           2          0 
         4 220           2          0 
         5 288           2          0 
         6 402           2          0 
         7 348           2          0 
        10 152           2          0 
        14 029           2          0 
        16 325           2          0 
        17 549           2          0 
        22 001           2          0
```

Comment: Hi MT0, thanks for your response. As stated in my original post, however, I only have read access to this table, so a DELETE will not work. Could we rework this into a MINUS somehow from my current query?

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Updated to just a `SELECT`.

Comment: Running this as is produces far too many results, and I'm still seeing paired records.

Comment: Also, please do not rely on the e_date for ordering as they can often be identical. The only true means of ordering is via ce_id.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius you might want to make that clear in the question as it was not mentioned anywhere before your comment.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Updated

Comment: Removals for edit #2 should be as follows: (Rows 8&9, 11&12, 14&15, 19&20). Also, as mentioned in a post above, there wouldn't be two "1's" in a row for sub_id, so rows 20&21 are an impossible case. Your newest query, however, narrows the recordset down to 21 rows. We are expecting 17 total, so this is much closer. Still seeing pairs in here. Hopefully this comment will make things more clear. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Why 14 & 15? They have different `C_ID`s? Also, your edit to the question shows the exact case where there are two consecutive rows where the `SUB_ID` is 1 - the rows have different `C_ID`s though (and it is the same in my example).

Comment: You're right, I wasn't looking at the C_ID... The REAL removals should be: (8&9, 11&12, 19&20)

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Which is exactly what my Query 1 produces... if there are other edge cases that I am not considering then please can you provide some sample data to highlight them. Query 2 is a version of the currently accepted answer that does not require self-joins - however, I think both that answer and my Query 2 are deleting too many rows.

Comment: Your first query returns 205 rows, so that can't be right. Your second query returns 21, which is much closer, but still has the wrong result set. The selected answer returns exactly the rows I am expecting to see. I will create another sample data image via a third edit of the original post.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Rather than posting an image - can you post the DML statements necessary to create the sample data so that it can just be copy/pasted into a test.

Comment: Edited with DML statements included.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius http://rextester.com/LKF43473 Not seeing any difference between my query 1 and vkp's answer for your new dataset; both return the same 19 rows.

Comment: See my edit to vkp's query in the following link. It contains the actual query I use. If you can apply it to your query, I will try to run it and get back to you on the results. Edited due to semicolon misplaced: http://rextester.com/EVP65144

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to filter out records that have two values for `sub_id`.  This suggests using analytic functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             count(distinct sub_id) over (partition by c_id) as numcid
      from e_table e
     ) e
where numcid = 1;
```

Also, your sample code has date logic in it, but the question doesn't mention that at all.

If the above isn't quite the right logic, I'm pretty sure analytic functions can do what you want.

EDIT:

If you are just looking for places where a "1" occurs after a "2", then use conditional aggregation:

```
select e.c_id
from (select e.c_id,
             min(case when sub_id = 1 then e_date end) as sub1_date,
             min(case when sub_id = 2 then e_date end) as sub2_date
      from e_table e
     ) e
where sub1_date > sub2_date;
```

You can readily modify this to get the original rows.

Comment: That is not exactly the approach I want to take. Consider the second pair of highlighted rows in my current output. Notice how the next row's c_id afterwards is 062 as well? I need that record to stay put. That is why I think this needs to happen in a sequential manner, such as with a loop.